# want to add one more condition in findAll

Tags: yii

the query is

```
 $model = Recipe::model()->findAll(array("condition" => "title like '$request%'"));
```

i want to add one more condition , status = Approved

is it good to add second condition in this findAll or use findallbyattributes and how to add second condition in this findAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should simply work -

`$model = Recipe::model()->findAll(array("condition" => "title like '$request%' and status = 'Approved'"));`

Answer (score 1):

You could just add `AND status = "Approved"`, but I think the best approach would be to use a `CDbCriteria`, like this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addSearchCondition($request);
$criteria->compare('status', 'Approved');
$model = Recipe::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

What do you think?